# Executing arbitrary javascript from Android WebView callback/interface

Tags: javascript, android

I have set up a very simple javascript implementation using Android's WebView:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Test.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

MyJavaScript.java

```
public class MyJavaScript 
{
    public MyJavaScript()
    {
        // create the WebView
        mWebView = new WebView(mContext);

        // enable javaScript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // add javaScript interface
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptTest, "_test");

        // load our dummy page
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/javascript/index.html");
    }

    public void exec(String script)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + script);
    }
}
```

Test.js

```
function Test()
{
};

Test.prototype.foo = function()
{
    window._test.foo();
};

Test.prototype.bar = function()
{
    window._test.bar();
};

var test = new Test();
```

JavaScriptTest.java

```
public class JavaScriptTest
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Log.d("Test", "foo");
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        Log.d("Test", "bar");
    }
}
```

When a caller calls something like:

```
MyJavaScript.exec("foo();");
```

Execution is ultimately propagated to JavaScriptTest.foo().  This execution is in the WebView's worker thread.

What I would like to do in JavaScriptTest.foo(), is something like eval("bar();");.  I basically want to synchronously execute more javascript from the java callback/interface.  That is, I want the javascript bar() method to fully execute before returning to JavaScriptTest.foo().  I can not figure out how to do this.

If I back up one layer, it is trivial to call bar(); from the foo method in Test.js.  However, this doesn't really meet my needs.  I need to be able to execute arbitrary javascript discovered by JavaScriptTest.foo() within JavaScriptTest.foo().

And because JavaScripTest.foo() is executing in the WebView's worker thread, passing the arbitrary javascript discovered by JavaScriptTest.foo() to WebView.loadUrl(...) won't work because you need call that API from the UI thread.

Ideally there would be a way to execute some arbitrary javascript while in the java callback/interface stub which is executing in WebView's worker thread.

I can probably solve the problem by passing the arbitrary javascript back to foo() in Test.js, but it would be a less generic and uglier solution than my first choice.  If my first choice doesn't exist, then I don't have an option.

Comment: Do you need bar() to execute synchronously inside JavascriptTest.foo(), i.e. before foo() returns to the JavaScript?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for bringing that up.  I should include that detail in the Description.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the threading requirements of the WebView, I don't think that you can achieve what you want I'm afraid. The only way to start a new javascript execution in Java from the background thread would be to post a task back to the UI thread, but that break your synchronous needs.

I think your only option is to have the Java object return a String back to your JavaScript and then eval it (as you are suggesting, I think).

Comment: Could I somehow pass the eval capability into the java code, i.e. window._test.foo(function(script) { return eval(script); } ); ?  What would the callback/interface in JavaScriptTest look like?  public void foo(???)?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your JavaScriptTest interface to return the javascript you want to evaluate.

```
public class JavaScriptTest
{
    public String foo()
    {
        return "bar();"
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        Log.d("Test", "bar");
    }
}
```

Then in your javascript:

```
function Test()
{
};

Test.prototype.foo = function()
{
    eval(window._test.foo());
};

Test.prototype.bar = function()
{
    window._test.bar();
};

var test = new Test();
```

You wouldn't have bar() evaluated before returning but you could do it immediately afterwards.